# Is ATL and MFC free? Is there a license limiting distribution of retail software?

Tags: mfc, atl

I'm interested in learning ATL to ease COM development but I'm concerned if ATL library is free in terms of distribution of software built with ATL headers?

do I have to pay anything to be able to use ATL and freely distribute completed software?

Comment: It's all free. I think there are some restrictions on MFC feature pack toolbar etc. but only if you make a product which competes with Microsoft Office. But those features are ugly and outdated anyway.

Comment: No fee. Don't even have to say you use it. We've been using and releasing software using ATL since ATL came out.

Comment: I think they are free if you own a valid license of Visual Studio. There is Visual Studio Community Edition, which is free for non-commercial use and even commercially for single developer.